# Warning error while starting Tor service in Kali

Tags: kali-linux, services, tor

I'm facing the below-mentioned issue while starting Tor service using command, ‘Tor service’, in Kali terminal, if anyone could help me out to fix this it would be a big help.

```
root@kali:~# tor service
May 26 05:37:11.442 [notice] Tor 0.4.5.7 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.12-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.1i, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.5, Libzstd 1.4.8 and Glibc 2.31 as libc.
May 26 05:37:11.442 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
May 26 05:37:11.442 [warn] Command-line option 'service' with no value. Failing.
May 26 05:37:11.442 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
root@kali:~#
```

Comment: What exact command have you used ?

Comment: I used ‘Tor service’.

Answer (score 1):

You can start tor service with:

```
sudo systemctl start tor
```

to check the status:

```
systemctl status tor
```

or you can use:

```
sudo service tor start
```

Comment: **root@kali:~# sudo systemctl start|status|stop|restart tor* 

Too few arguments.
Command 'restart' not found, did you mean:
  command 'restartd' from deb restartd
  command 'rstart' from deb x11-session-utils
Try: apt install <deb name>
Command 'stop' not found, but there are 17 similar ones.
Command 'status' not found, did you mean:
  command 'qstatus' from deb gridengine-client
  command 'statfs' from deb gocryptfs
  command 'states' from deb enscript
Try: apt install <deb name>

Comment: *root@kali:~# sudo service tor  start|stop|status|restart* 

Command 'stop' not found, but there are 17 similar ones.
Command 'restart' not found, did you mean:
  command 'rstart' from deb x11-session-utils
  command 'restartd' from deb restartd
Try: apt install <deb name>
Command 'status' not found, did you mean:
  command 'statfs' from deb gocryptfs
  command 'states' from deb enscript
  command 'qstatus' from deb gridengine-client
Try: apt install <deb name>

Comment: I tried all the command you suggested but nothing happened. I shared the terminal above in two comments.

Comment: @LalitKashyap see my edit

Comment: I tried ‘systemctl status tor’ command it shows status ‘Active’ in green but my IP address wasn't changed. I tried other two command as well but nothing happened.

Comment: ● tor.service - Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/tor.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Thu 2021-05-27 02:40:41 IST; 16min ago                                                                                                                                                                   
    Process: 2033 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Comment: @LalitKashyap The tor service is running correctly.

Comment: Thanks!! a lot 